# Mysql insert queries stores the data in different order

Tags: mysql

I am writing insert queries dynamically and executing as well. My insert queries are:

```
INSERT INTO b_records (b_record_id) VALUES ('ac_dashboard_filters');
INSERT INTO b_records (b_record_id) VALUES ('ac_exec_data');
INSERT INTO b_records (b_record_id) VALUES ('ac_filter');
INSERT INTO b_records (b_record_id) VALUES ('ac_permission');
INSERT INTO b_records (b_record_id) VALUES ('ac_preview_data');
INSERT INTO b_records (b_record_id) VALUES ('account');
INSERT INTO b_records (b_record_id) VALUES ('acct2channel_account');
```

But, when I am selecting the records from the table b_records, records are like that:

```
| b_record_id                       |
+--------------------------------------+
| account                              |
| acct2channel_account                 |
| ac_dashboard_filters                 |
| ac_exec_data                         |
| ac_filter                            |
| ac_permission                        |
| ac_preview_data                      |
```

Why, I am not getting the data in the same order as insert queries are. Can anyone please suggest me.

Comment: Forget about the order of data as it appears in the table, order only applies when you query with an `ORDER BY` clause.  If you want an order, add a column that contains a value that will yield the correct order when sorted and `ORDER BY` it.

Comment: absent an `order by` clause, there's nothing in a DB that really specifies that the order you stuff something into the db is the same order that something will come back out in.

Answer (score 0):

> Why, I am not getting the data in the same order as insert queries are

That's cause there is no inherent order by default using which data will be stored and so you will have use `order by` clause while fetching the data to sort the data per your need (default is `ascending`) like

```
select b_record_id 
from b_records
order by b_record_id desc
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL does not guarantee order of data, if you don't use *order by* clause in your query. It *may* return results in the order you inserted them in some cases, but it's really bad idea to rely on this, because it can change when the table is optimized or imported in a different server.

I would advise you to add "id" field as a primary key with auto increment (if you don't already have one) and use it for ordering.